# Stop splitter from scaling panels in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, splitcontainer

I have a SplitContainer with both panels filled.
When I resize it, tho, both panels scale equally so the splitter is at the same relative distance in the container.
I really need to block this feature. How do I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Take a look at the [`FixedPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.fixedpanel.aspx) property.  You can then specify if you want `Panel1` or `Panel2` fixed.  The three options are:

> None (This is the default)
>
> Specifies that neither SplitContainer.Panel1, SplitContainer.Panel2 is fixed. A Control.Resize event affects both panels.
>
> Panel1
>
> Specifies that SplitContainer.Panel1 is fixed. A Control.Resize event affects only SplitContainer.Panel2.
>
> Panel2
>
> Specifies that SplitContainer.Panel2 is fixed. A Control.Resize event affects only SplitContainer.Panel1.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `FixedPanel` Property of the splitter to specify wich panel will scale. By default it is set to `None` so both will scale.

Comment: Sorry but the other answer was 16 seconds quicker... You get the rep tho.